# Whats the ruby syntax for calling a method with multiple parameters and a block?

Tags: ruby, syntax, dsl, ruby-2.0

Ruby doesn't like this:

```
item (:name, :text) {
  label('Name')
}
```

And I don't know why. I'm attempting to create a DSL. The 'item' method looks like this:

```
def item(name, type, &block) 
  i = QbeItemBuilder.new(@ds, name, QbeType.gettype(type))
  i.instance_exec &block
end
```

Take a name for the item, a type for the item, and a block. Construct an item builder, and execute the block in its context.

Regardless of whether or not I need to use instance_exec (I'm thinking that I don't - it can be stuffed in the initialiser), I get this:

```
SyntaxError (ds_name.ds:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
  item (:name, :text) {
              ^
```

How do I invoke method with multiple arguments and a block? What does ruby think I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space before parentheses is causing ruby to evaluate `(:name, :text)` as single argument before calling the method which results in a syntax error. Look at these examples for illustration:

```
puts 1      # equivalent to puts(1)       - valid
puts (1)    # equivalent to puts((1))     - valid
puts (1..2) # equivalent to puts((1..2))  - valid
puts (1, 2) # equivalent to puts((1, 2))  - syntax error
puts(1, 2)  # valid
```

Your way of providing the block is syntactically valid, however when the block is not in the same line as the method call it is usually better to use `do ... end` syntax.

So to answer your question you can use:

```
item(:name, :text) { label('Name') }
```

or:

```
item(:name, :text) do
  label('Name')
end
```

Comment: Arrgh! Arrgh! It's attempting to evaluate the parenthesed but as an expression!
Thanks, man.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space before the `(` in `item (:name, :text) {`

Comment: Not supposed to put a space between the parenthesis and the argument.